# MefBootStrapper and splash screen

Tags: c#, splash-screen, mef

Using Prism with MEF. Where would you, logically, in the bootstrapper sequence put functionality for a splash screen.

Answer (score 1):

In the loader (the module starting and collecting the elements), before the applicaiton starts. Actually not even managed by .NET but by the special splash screen functionality, obvsiouly.

http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/05/creating-splash-screen-without-code.html

shows how to add an image to a .NET application and set it as splash screen through a build action.

THAT basically runs even before the .NET runtime is totally fully loaded.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I cant do like that as i need the eventaggregator to notify users in the splash screen about module initialization. So i need to resolve the splash screen module initiallly before i initialize the rest of the modules.

Comment: Then still do it in the loader, it is not part of the modules.

Answer (score 0):

@keydet has highlight the tips and tricks to improve the WPF Startup performance with MEF and a Splash Screen , and i think you can also add-on eventaggregator to notify users in the during the initialization.

More going to [Improving perceived WPF app startup performance with MEF and a Splash Screen](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/keydet/improving-perceived-wpf-app-startup-performance-with-mef-and-a-splash-screen) . Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks i saw that video, but my problem is where to resolve the splash screen module and inject the eventaggregator

Comment: Why would you need to do in the Module ? it should be in the loader

Comment: As my modules takes some time to load i need to present progress in the splash screen. I thougt i could do it by publishing events from the initialize phase of each module that the splash screen could respond to

Comment: you can register the common controller(for e.g application control) and subscribe the application_loadCompleted. And on the other hand, if  your ViewModel class publishing the application_loadCompleted when loading is completed.